# onResume for WallpaperService

Tags: android, service, android-preferences, live-wallpaper

Is there a method like onResume for WallpaperService?

I tried:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

but it tells me that **The method onResume() is undefined for the type WallpaperService**

I want my wallpaper to refresh itself after new values have been given by user, in preferences.

So I was wondering if there is method like onResume for WallpaperService? or is there a better way to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no onResume() method in wallpaper engine. TO listen preferences you need to implement 
shared preference listener and you can get the changed value.